# Is it possible to do URL rewriting on a Tornado web server?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amazon-ec2, url-rewriting, tornado

I'm planning on installing [Thumbor](https://github.com/thumbor/thumbor), an open-source image thumbnailing program written in Python, on an Amazon EC2 instance running Amazon Linux. According to [Thumbor's documentation](https://github.com/thumbor/thumbor/wiki/Requirements):

> thumbor uses the Tornado web server (http://www.tornadoweb.org/), which is automatically installed.

I'm used to doing RewriteRules on Apache servers, but I confess I've never used Tornado before. I'm going to need to do some URL rewriting for the requests coming into thumbor (I want to be able to take query parameters and effectively move them into the path), but realize I can't just drop an .htaccess file in there as that's specific to Apache.

Does Tornado have out-of-the-box support for URL rewriting?

More specifically, here are the RewriteRules I would have used if this would have been on Apache:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)height=(\d+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)width=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^legacy/thumbor$ /%2x%1/image.jpg? [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Tornado is not a generic web server in the way that apache is; it's a platform for building application-specific servers. If you're building your own application then you can handle URLs however you want, but if you're using an off-the-shelf application like thumbor there is no generic higher-level configuration system that would let you do something like this.

Instead, it is typical to run nginx or apache (with mod_proxy) in front of your tornado-based service(s), and do any necessary URL rewriting at that layer.